# Having a hard time understanding this equation in monocular EKF SLAM

Tags: localization, slam, navigation, ekf, mapping

Reading this paper on [visual odometry](http://e-collection.library.ethz.ch/eserv/eth:48374/eth-48374-01.pdf), where they have used a bearing vector to parameterize the features. I am having a hard time understanding what the state propagation equation for the bearing vector term means :

[image: Bearing vector and inverse depth parametrization]

The vector N is not mentioned in the equations, so its not very clear what it does. Would really appreciate if someone would help me understand it :)

Answer (score 1):

The text says:

> [...] where $N^T (\mu)$ linearly projects a 3D vector onto the 2D
>   tangent space around the bearing vector $\mu$ [...]

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to get an intuitive understanding of what that means, plus how the equation comes up with those three terms, i.e. relating bearing vector with w and v and w(u,i)

Comment: Maybe you could rephrase your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the notation represents taking an arbitrary 3-vector, applying a rotation matrix to the 3-vector based on the bearing 3-vector, and then removing one of the dimensions of the result.  If the arbitrary 3-vector and the bearing 3-vector are the same, then the result of the rotation should be [ 1 0 0 ], and the first coordinate would be removed, since the projection of that vector onto the plane orthogonal to it is zero.  For an arbitrary 3-vector, you get the components of the projection onto a plane that is normal to the bearing 3-vector.

As to how to compute the rotation matrix based on the bearing 3-vector, I would defer to the following:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114512/how-to-find-the-orthonormal-transformation-that-will-rotate-a-vector-to-the-x-ax